# Image of a set by the transformation: $\tan(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$, $z \rightarrow T(z) = \tan(z)$.

Consider the set: $\Omega = \{z = x + iy \in \mathbb C, \ x \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2), \ y \in \mathbb R \}$

> Prove that $\Omega ' := \mathbb C \setminus \{\omega = u + iv, \ u = 0, \ v \in (-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty) \}$ is the image of $\Omega$ by $T$.

**Work:**

We can write $T$ in a more pleasant form: $$T(z) = i\left( \frac{1 - e^{2iz}}{1 + e^{2iz}} \right)$$

Let's try to find the most explicit form of $T$:

$$T(z) = T(x+iy) = \ldots = \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2 x)+\cosh(2 y)}+i \frac{\sinh(2 y)}{ \cos(2 x)+ \cosh(2 y)}$$

This doesn't give me any clue about why need $\Omega '$ be the image of $\Omega$. I tried some things, but I am still an amateur in complex analysis, and I would appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your first line: $\tan z$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb {C},$ so out of the gate there is a little problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO the best way to solve this is to break the transformation down into simple transformations and apply them successively.  Extending your formula for $T(z)$, we have
$$T(z)=i\Bigl(-1+\frac2{1+e^{2iz}}\Bigr)\ :$$
the reason I have written it this way is that now $z$ occurs only once in the formula.

We now see what happens to complex numbers $z\in\Omega$ if we apply this formula step by step.  The best way to understand it is to draw diagrams, but I am not good at posting diagrams online so I will leave that part of it up to you.

Firstly, we have
$$e^{2iz}=e^{-2y}e^{2ix}\ .$$
For $z\in\Omega$, the modulus $e^{-2y}$ can be any positive real number, and $e^{2ix}$ can be any point on the unit circle except for $-1$.  Multiplying these (this is where a diagram will be really helpful), $e^{2iz}$ takes all complex values except for the negative real axis (including the origin).

Now $1+e^{2iz}$ shifts everything $1$ unit to the right.  So now we have all complex numbers except for real numbers $x\le-1$.

If we take the reciprocal of all real numbers $x\le1$, we get all real numbers $x'\ge1$ together with all real numbers $x'<0$.  So taking the reciprocal of $1+e^{2iz}$, we don't get these numbers.  We also don't get the origin.  So the image of $\Omega$ under the transform
$$z\mapsto\frac1{1+e^{2iz}}$$
consists of all complex numbers except for real $x\ge1$ and real $x\le0$.

The rest is downhill.  Multiply by $2$ and add $-1$: we get all complex numbers except for real $x\ge1$ and real $x\le-1$.  Finally, multiply by $i$: this rotates the plane through a right angle, so we have all of $\Bbb C$ except for the set you have indicated.

Comment: Apologies for the mistake, I have edited the post. Thank you.

Comment: No problem!  I have slightly edited my answer to match the corrected question.

Comment: I am trying to find a holomorphic $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $D$ is simply connected and $f(D)$ is doubly connected. Do you have any idea on how to find such an $f$?